# setText in basic Android app

Tags: android, android-emulator

anybody knows why this program won't display "hey" string(in Emulator)? Instead it displays "Large text".

```
package com.seba.numberShow;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       tv.setText("hey");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the xml for second.xml?

Comment: check your layout file its right ?

Comment: try to clean the project and run

Comment: is it showing blank screen or there is any error ?

Comment: i cleaned it and know it works, thanks

Comment: place your answer here and accept it, otherwise it will be in UnAnswered question

Answer (score 0):

in your xml: your textView id parameter is not same as in java code,
here:

`TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

Check the Resource id

> R.id.textView1 this would be differnt